# Some artisan commands are not working

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am creating a log in system and in which I want to create admin panal and dashboard but I have created table already and I want to add "isAdmin" column in my existing table.

I have watched several tutorials but all is vain. I am using Laravel 5+ version. I have used `php artisan migrate:refresh` command and rollback command but all these not working.

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('isAdmin');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

Comment: Can you please expand your post with more information about the error that you're seeing?

Comment: my problam is simple the php artisan commands like php artisan rollback or fresh these commands are not working i just want to add  field i 'admin' in my existing table according to documentation php artisan:fresh command will do this but it is not working..

Comment: i cant change any thing of my table is it for because i have created this from auth command or any other issue?

Comment: But what do you mean by not working? Are you seeing an error? It doesn't create them without an error?

Comment: no its a logical error.. whatever normal user come or admin it redirect both on same page the index home page the condition of if is meaning less here

Comment: sorry for above comment that was wrong. actually the command are not valid according to cmd i am using laravel 5.5 version and also take commands from 5.5 documentation

Comment: i just add one column is my existing table and for this i use the command refresh but it shows me error